# C# Implementing DllMain with DllExport

Tags: c#, dllexport, dllmain

I'm using [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) By RobertGiesecke

I want to export [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) entrypoint.

Here what I've tried

```
[DllExport("DllMain", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static bool DllMain(IntPtr hModule, uint dwReason, byte[] lpReserved)
{ 
  // I Write a text to file here
  return true; 
}
```

Then I call [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) but nothing happens. Any solution?

Comment: This unmanaged exports: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports ?

Comment: That's not possible.  Giesecke's utility provides exports.  DllMain() is not exported, it is the *entrypoint* for a DLL.  Modifying the entrypoint for a managed assembly is not possible, it is already used.  It calls _CorDllMain(), the CLR requires that call.  You'll need to use C++/CLI to do this.  Or a module initializer, not supported in C# but can be bolted on.

Comment: @Theraot, Hi yes.

Comment: @moien I don't think there is a solution with UnmanagedExport right now. They have the open issue [Can i export a method just called 'DllMain'?](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/5) - see also [Difference between DllMain and DllEntryPoint](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2089). Edit: I'm unaware of alternatives that allow this.

Comment: @Theraot, thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

Hooray, I found a way by using static constructor.

Just make class that contains exports static, and add static method.

```
public static class Class1
{
    static Class1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DLL MAIN (Only DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) :D");
    }

    [DllExport("AddFunc", CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int AddFunc(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b + 1;
    }
}
```

When AddFunc called, Program first call Class1(Only one time) next call AddFunc

Anyway for DLL_PROCESS_DETACH ?

Comment: Hmm, where to begin? (1.) You didn't mention anything about the 3rd-party library you're using for the `DllExport` feature. (2.) But you actually don't need it anyway; .NET will always ensure that your ***type initializer*** method (`static Class1() { }`)  is called before any other static or instance method of the class. (3.) So you haven't solved the OP's problem, because you still require some external party to proactively call a (any) method in `Class1`, as opposed to somehow getting control as a direct consequence of `DllMain`. For example, if you have another `static Class2`, then...

Comment: ...that activity would cause your `DllMain` to be entered without "waking-up" or having any effect on `Class1` at all, let alone display your "DLL MAIN..." message. In fact, it's entirely legitimate for the process to do a non-abnormal exit, after having called `DllMain` a long, long time ago, and yet never having called your `Class1` type-initializer.

Comment: @GlennSlayden, At beginning of question I wrote "Im Using UnmanagedExports By RobertGiesecke" and did I accepted my own answer ? It means the problem still remains.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't see that you were answering your own question. Perhaps next time, if you have more information to give, consider editing the original question, so that it will be clear to everyone that the topic remains unanswered.

Comment: @GlennSlayden, No problem. Your right, I have to edit the question instead posting an answer. Thanks.