# Can I have DllMain in C# for DLL injection?

Tags: c#, dll, dllexport

I want to do like normal DLL injection, but calls DllMain in C#.

I'm using [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) to export my DllMain but the entry point doesn't end up being called when I inject the DLL into any arbitary process. I had to specify that DllMain function to be invoked in my DLL injector.

I can almost achieve it in C++/CLI but a deadlock occurs whe DllMain are being called in managed code section because of loader lock in CLR initialization.

I also tried [MemoryModule](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule), first load my embeded Pure IL DLL, and then to call my exported DllMain procedure to see any luck bootstraping the code, but it fails nonetheless: the PE header of a MSIL library is incomplete.

So how do I make my DllMain exported visible to Windows to call it automatically like C/C++ whenever a DLL injection of that particular C# DLL occur?

Comment: Exact same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933033/c-sharp-implementing-dllmain-with-dllexport).  So no.

Comment: Have you tried using static constructor ? It will be called first time